# RC2 and PKCS7 Encryption in iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, encryption, pkcs#7

I'm trying to encrypt data using RC2 algorithm with PKCS7 padding in Android and iOS, but results are different.

I need to get the exact results. The KEY and IV are already provided but I'm not sure what to do with them. I need to get the same result as the codes in ios.

Values for

```
IV = "11223344"
KEY = "Sample"
```

IOS Code:

```
NSString *iv = IV ;

NSData *data = [s dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
//key
NSString *key = KEY;

const char *keyPtr = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
const char *cIv = [iv cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSUInteger dataLength = [data length];

size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeRC2;
void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
//kCCBlockSizeAES128
size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt,
                                      kCCAlgorithmRC2,
                                      kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,keyPtr,
                                      [key length],
                                      cIv,
                                      [data bytes],
                                      dataLength,
                                      buffer,
                                      bufferSize,
                                      &numBytesEncrypted);
```

Android Code:

```
 SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Constant.RC2_KEY.getBytes("US-ASCII"), "PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC");
 IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(Constant.RC2_IV.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
 cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
 byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data);
 return encrypted;
```

With this code, the cipher.init() does not execute and it results to an error. but when i change **"AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding"** or **"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"** to **"PBEWITHSHAAND128BITRC2-CBC"** it doesn't. It encrypts the data but different from the ios code's result.

```
 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
 cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
```

Can anyone please help me solve this encryption thingy?

Comment: Might be helpful to provide example input data and expected outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java code looks quite broken - you certainly don't want to be referencing AES as your algorithm.

The following code will use RC2 correctly. I don't have the capability to test your iOS code, so perhaps there are other problems too.

```
byte[] iv = "87654321".getBytes("US-ASCII");
byte[] key = "SampleKey".getBytes("US-ASCII");
byte[] data = new byte[30]; // for example

SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "RC2");

RC2ParameterSpec ivSpec = new RC2ParameterSpec(key.length * 8, iv);

Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RC2/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivSpec);
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data);

// ....
```

*Note the use of `RC2ParameterSpec`, which is required by the algorithm, plus the reference to `PKCS5Padding` rather than `PKCS7Padding`.*

Comment: may I know what key.length * 8 mean?

Comment: I tried running the code but it errors during Cipher.getInstance();

Comment: @sarenagay Read the Javadocs for [`RC2ParameterSpec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/RC2ParameterSpec.html#RC2ParameterSpec%28int,%20byte[]%29). It explains that you need to provide the key size in bits, hence "`key.length * 8`". Please post the stacktrace of your error.

Comment: I try to catch the exception but it doesn't output anything. I only found out that it's an error because I traced it using the debugger. and it does not proceed to the next line after Cipher.getInstance(). Is it required to use Bouncy Castle? I'm not using bouncy castle right now.

Comment: @sarenagay The code above worked for me without BouncyCastle installed, just using normal Java 7. So does your program terminate then? Or does it hang on that line? If it terminates, I'd be really surprised if you can't catch an exception (perhaps try catching `Throwable`)?

Comment: Hi Mr. Dunca, I'm sorry for the very late reply. I found the exception, it says "No such algorithm - RC2/CBC/PKCS5Padding". i haven't found a solution to this problem yet. :(